# How do you determine the growth of the functions $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^k,\ g(n)=n^{k+1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

My objective here is to determine the asymptotic growth relationship between the following two functions:
$$f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^ni^k,\quad g(n)=n^{k+1}.$$

Previously what I have been doing is graphing the two over a range of n, and gauging based on that growth what the relationship is, and indicating whether f = O(g), f = Ω(g), or both (i.e., f = Θ(g)).

I an confused on how to do this for a summation, as the range now not only covers n but the variable k as well. How do you determine the growth of such functions?

Comment: The summation doesn't affect this strategy other than possibly requiring other methods to graph (depends whether your graphing program understands summation).  You probably should start by ignoring the fact that $k$ is a parameter, and just try a fixed value of $k$.  Then another, and another, then try to detect a pattern.

Comment: There is a subtle (probably unintended) aspect of this question in that it is true that $f = \Theta(g)$ for any fixed value of $k>-1$, but not uniformly across all such $k$.  So it wouldn't be accurate to say that $f=\Theta(g)$ but $f=\Theta_k(g)$ is fair (for $k>-1$).

Comment: Hint: $f(n) \le n \cdot n^k  = g(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$. Also, for even $n$ $$
f(n) \ge \frac{n}{2}\left( {\frac{n}{2}} \right)^k  = 2^{ - k - 1} g(n)
$$ and I left the odd case to you.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is fixed, then  $f(n)/g(n)$ is a Riemann sum.
$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^k\longrightarrow\int_0^1x^kdx=\frac 1 {k+1}$$
thus
$$f(n)\sim \frac{g(n)}{k+1}$$